# What are the exact dimensions/specs of the fittings on a standard stainless steel Hansen Coupler?

Tags: equipment, keg, corny-keg

I have a standard stainless steel Hansen Coupler for Pin-Lock type Cornelius Kegs.  I'm trying to find the exact specs on both the 1/4 MFL and the inside (female) threads, where it connects to the actual pin lock coupler.

The coupler and the 90 degree elbow unscrew, and the coupler itself has a male threaded end that I've seen various places refer to as 7/8-14 and 5/8 BSP - but it doesn't seem quite that big.  Is that correct, or is it something else?

What exactly is a 1/4 MFL in normal terms?  Is it a 1/4in SAE 45 degree flared connector, or is it a 37 degree AN style connector?  Or something else all together?

[the one I have looks like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049MDVLU)

Answer (score 1):

Well, partial answer - I went to the local pipe fitting shop, and I found that the 1/4" MFL is a 45* SAE 1/4" flare connector - it is also compatible with the 37* -4AN connector.

I'm still at a loss as to the threads on the disconnect itself though...

Comment: When you say 1/4" SAE, do you mean 45* SAE for a 1/4" tube? https://www.ryco.com.au/technical/thread-connector-identification/sae-threads/ lists specs for the threads, and suggests 7/16-20, and I've seen some vendors selling what looks like the right fitting as a 7/16 SAE fitting. Does that gel with what you've found?